# How to make an Excel line chart ignore certain cells?

Tags: excel, charts

I have monthly values in a column with cumulative values in the adjacent column.  The cumulative calculation should only work where there is data for that month so I have used formulas such as =IF(E6>0,F5+E6,"")

I need a line chart showing the cumulative results but I don't want Excel to plot the cells containing ""   Is this possible, using either chart options, or by changing the cumulative formula?

I've tried to post a picture of my chart but I'm new here so it won't allow me to.  Let's see if it allows a link to mediafire instead.

In my picture (if you can see it)  I want the red line for 2015 to stop at March, instead of plotting zeroes for the rest of the year.

[Link to screenshot](http://www.mediafire.com/view/191aus3f4zhz9do/chart_problem.PNG)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use:

```
 =IF(E6>0,F5+E6,NA())
```

It will display `#N/A` instead of empty string. If it doesn't look OK, you could create a helper column with this formula, add it to chart, and hide this column.

Comment: Thank you.  That works!!  I didn't know about the NA() function so that would never have occurred to me.  I really appreciate that!